# Problema con el uso de clases python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos

cuando ejecuto mi programa me da este error:

> nueva = colonia.Colonia(self.__tareas,self.__veces)
>   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'colonia' referenced before assignment

mi clase es la siguiente:

```
import tareas
import hormiga
import colonia
class inicio:
def __init__(self):
    self.__nHormigas = 20 #mAnts
    self.__veces = 4 #mIter
    self.__generaciones = 500 #mHillsCount
    self.__alfa = 1
    self.__beta = 1 
    self.__p = 0.1 #mEvap
    self.__nTareas = 100
    self.__mColonia = [] #mHills
    self.__tareas = []
    self.__mMejorRuta = []

def getMejorCoste(self):
    return self.__mejorCoste #mBestCost

def getRuta(self):
    return self.__mMejorRuta #mBestPath

def Iniciar(self):
    self.__mejorCoste = float('inf')
    for e in range(self.__nTareas):
        tarea = tareas.Tarea()
        self.__tareas.append(tarea)
    for i in range(self.__generaciones):
        nueva = colonia.Colonia(self.__tareas,self.__veces) #aquí es el error
        self.__mColonia.append(nueva)
    #en paralelo??
    for colonia in self.__mColonia:
        colonia.empezar()
    self.__mColonia.sort(key=lambda x: x.getMejorCoste())
    if (self.__mColonia[0].getMejorCoste() < self.__mejorCoste):
        self.__mejorCoste = self.__mColonia[0].getMejorCoste()
        self.__mMejorRuta = []
        for tarea in self.__mColonia[0].getMejorRuta():
            self.__mMejorRuta.append(tarea)
    print(self.__mejorCoste)
```

Mi directorio de ficheros contiene uno que se llama colonia.py cuyo contructor es el siguiente:

```
class Colonia:
def __init__ (self, tareas, n_iteraciones, evaporacion=0.1, n_hormigas=20):
    self.__constanteEvaporacion = evaporacion
    self.__nHormigas = n_hormigas
    self.__iteraciones = n_iteraciones
    self.__evaporacion = 1.0 - evaporacion
    self.__tareas = tareas

    self.__mejorCoste = float('inf')
    self.__mejorRuta = list()
    self.__hormigas = []
    #inicializamos matriz de feromonas
    self.__mFeromonas = [[getValorInicialFeromona()]*len(self.__tareas) for x in range(len(self.__tareas))]
    self.__feromonas = [[0.0]*len(self.__tareas) for x in range(len(self.__tareas))]
```

mi directorio.
[image: directorio]

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Comment: Es posible que te falte importar el modulo `colonia` para poder usarlo en tu clase `inicio`.

Comment: No, pero se me olvidó incluir los imports en stackoverflow, gracias por recordarlo :)

Comment: Una sugerencia: intenta seguir las convenciones de formato para código Python: PEP-8. Aquí puedes encontrar un resumen en español: https://bioinf.comav.upv.es/courses/linux/python/estilo.html

Comment: Yo apostaría a que el error es por el indent, copiando y pegando el código tal como está, no me deja ejecutarlo.

Comment: Revisá la identación de tu código. De todas maneras es raro que siga mostrando el mismo error si has importado bien el módulo `colonia`.

Comment: Si fuese la indentación debería darme un fallo de indentación, pero está bien

Comment: Has probado importando `from colonia import Colonia` y luego instanciar el objeto mediante: `nueva = Colonia(self.__tareas,self.__veces)`?

Comment: Parece que eso me ha solucionado el problema! gracias!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo que ver la estructura de tus directorios y archivos, si no lo solucionas con lo que te voy a comentar  añadela y editaré mi respuesta.

Asegurate de que el directorio donde se encuetra el modulo `colonia.py`también contiene el archivo `__init__.py` este sirve para indicar que el paquete (directorio donde se encuentra el `__init__.py`) contiene archivos python, de lo dontrario no se podrá importar los módulos.

Otra causa de el error puede ser una importación inadecuada:

si el modulo `colonia.py` se encuentra en otro paquete la importación correcta sería `from paquetex.colonia import Colonia`  y si esta en el mismo ``from colonia import Colonia`

la inicialización del objeto seria así:

`nueva = Colonia(self.__tareas,self.__veces)

Comment: no tengo el __init__ pero en modo consola he podido hacer importaciones  bien, :/

Comment: Crea el archivo, dejado vacío no hace falta que pongas nada

Comment: Sigue dándome el mismo error.

Comment: Cambiaste el modo de importar?

Comment: Sí, he hecho lo de nueva = Colonia(parametros) y nada.

Comment: En tu pregunta agrega la estructura de tus directorios y archivos y también actualiza tu código

Comment: Ya lo resolví, era hacer un from colonia import Colonia ^^ Gracias!

Comment: No habias cambiado el modo de importar :p
Genial , me alegro haber ayudado. No olvides marcar como pregunta respondida y dar el voto positivo de respuesta util. Un saludo

Comment: Eso intento, pero no hay ninguna respuesta con la solución que hice, solo son comentarios :S

Comment: XD la solución que usaste está incluida en la segunda solución que te plantie jejeje bueno no te preocupes saludos

Comment: sí, me di cuenta jajaja